# How to fetch data from two prometheus servers into single grafana dashboard?

Tags: prometheus, grafana-dashboard

I have metrics in two different prometheus servers, can I directly use both into single Grafana Dashboard? I have tried but not able to find any way to use 2 different sources into single Dashboard. Does anyone did similar things, if yes please share the steps.
Below is the reference to select data source in Grafana

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qp7R.png)

I have metrics in two different prometheus servers, can I directly use both into single Grafana Dashboard? I have tried but not able to find any way to use 2 different sources into single Dashboard. Does anyone did similar things, if yes please share the steps.

Comment: In the dropdown on your screenshot select -- Mixed --, and then for each query select respective Prometheus instance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two different datasources as prometheus named:

- prometheus-1
- prometheus-2

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/

Then in your dashboard go to variables and create a new variable which queries data sources.
ex: `query_result(datasources{type="prometheus"})`